# AWK Loop Over Multiple Columns

Tags: shell, awk, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

Please pretend I have the following situation (multiple columns & rows):

```
1/1:123:121 TAB 0/0:1:21 TAB 1/1:12:14
0/1:12:23 TAB 0/1:12:15 TAB 0/0:123:16
0/0:3:178 TAB 1/1:123:121 TAB 1/1:2:28
```

What would like to have is awk looping over each column and writing a new output under these conditions:

IF the firs field (which are separated by ":") is 1/1 OR 0/0,

then write "NA" TAB "NA"

ELSE

write the two numbers the the following fields, "Number 1" TAB "Number 2". Separator between columns should be TAB.

Thus, the desired outout the the example used above would be:

```
NA TAB NA TAB NA TAB NA TAB NA TAB NA
12 TAB 23 TAB 12 TAB 15 TAB NA TAB NA
NA TAB NA TAB NA TAB NA TAB NA TAB NA
```

Below is my current code, which work for the first column, but I do not know how to make it work for ALL columns in the file.

```
awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[1]"\t"a[2]"\t"a[3]}' |
awk -F"\t" '{
    if ($1 == "0/0" || $1 == "1/1")
        print $1="NA", $2="NA"
    else
        print $2"\t"$3
}'
```

Any ideas of how this could be achieved?

Many thanks in advance, George.

Comment: Show output of `bcftools query -f "[%GT:%AD\t]\n" MyVCF.vcf.gz` with your final expected output.

Comment: I believe that I just did what you asked for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show output of `bcftools` in **text format** along with your final expected output.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why do you want to loop over the columns? (and not over the rows?)

Comment: You say "my desired output would be something like this" but you don't tell us why that would be your desired output. Please [edit] your question to state what it is you want to **do** while you are looping over the columns. Don't assume we can figure out what you want to do by reading code you provide that doesn't do what you want to do.

Comment: I believe I asked it in a better way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' -F '[:\t]' '{
   s = ""
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=3)
      s = (s == "" ? "" : s OFS) ($i == "0/0" || $i == "1/1" ? "NA" OFS "NA" : $(i+1) OFS $(i+2))
   print s
}' file

NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12  23  12  15  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanging your notation of `TAB` correctly, would you please try:

```
awk -F"\t" '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        split($i, a, ":")
        if (a[1] == "0/0" || a[1] == "1/1") a[2] = a[3] = "NA"
        printf "%s\t%s%s", a[2], a[3], i == NF ? "\n" : "\t"
    }
}' input_file
```

where `input_file` looks like:

```
1/1:123:121     0/0:1:21        1/1:12:14
0/1:12:23       0/1:12:15       0/0:123:16
0/0:3:178       1/1:123:121     1/1:2:28
```

and the output:

```
NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
12      23      12      15      NA      NA
NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
 awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){split($i,a,","); if (a[1] == "0/0" || a[1] == "1/1") {printf " ""NA"" ""NA"} else {printf " "a[2]" "a[3]}} print""}' | cut -d " " -f2- > Test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A sed solution:

```
sed  's~\(0/0\|1/1\)[0-9:]\+~NA\tNA~g; s~./.:\([0-9]\+\)\:\([0-9]\+\)~\1\t\2~g' dat.tab  

NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12  23  12  15  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

first substitution NAs fields beginning with '0/0' or '1/1'
second substitution isolates and emits the trailing colon separated numbers from the field

(did tidy up output spacing)